# iOS app: Metadata rejected

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

So I just uploaded my first app to the `Apple Store` and there was one issue: `Metadata Reject: Design Copycat`

> Please make the necessary changes to your app so that it does not infringe upon the rights of a third party:
>
> - Remove all third-party marks from your app icon, screenshots, and previews.

1. I was wondering.. **Am I not allowed to use any images from the web in
   my preview?** My app is loading news items from an API. Each item has
   an image (not taken by me), which is shown on the main page.
2. Also, if it's just metadata.. **Does this mean I only have to change
   my app icon that will be visible in the store** or also the real app
   icon you'll see on your phone?
3. If they're having an issue with the images in my screenshots.. **Will
   they also have an issue with the actual app showing those images?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue refers specifically about options 2 and 3 from your question. You can discard #1 for sure.

Without seeing your app icon, previews and screenshots it's hard to tell what's wrong with them but it's definitely something that's already somewhere else. It could be another app with the same icon set or very similar previews. Do not discard the possibility that it could also be *part* of your app icon or previews, are you including logos or slogans from 3rd party companies?

If your app previews have this images that the API is pulling from different sources you may want to tweak them to show some other images, just for the previews and screenshots not the actual app.

For #2 the recommendation will be to have the same icon in the app than in the store. Mostly because users can identify quickly.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post with the screenshots I uploaded.. Sorry it's so big

Comment: By looking at your screenshots it's easy to say that the issue are those and not the app icon. Try showing the features of your app instead of the actual content. For example: instead of putting a screenshot of a video, do an image that say: "Play your favorite videos"

Comment: Doesn't it have to be a real screenshot of the app then? Can I just put an image with that text centered for example?

Comment: The [iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html) documentation specifies the sizes and properties of the screenshot but the content may vary. While many apps have just "screenshots" of the actual app, there are some that have more marketing and design around them, for example [Microsoft Excel iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-excel/id586683407?mt=8) has a more complex design. You can do what it best for your app, just remember that the copyright of videos may reject it.

Comment: So, is this resolved? What details you required to get app approved? Also, are Apple verified this authorised document (PDF) or after submitting the authorised letter (PDF) they are approving the app. Please share your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a screenshot of your app that contains potentially infringing data? If so, you may want to replace that screenshot & respond once you do that.

For your third point, you should be fine so long as you disclose that your app consumes third party content.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post with 2 screenshots.. The icon was also an image

Comment: @Greg IANAL, but I can see how they would flag those images. Would recommend finding some other kind of image you can use to convey what your app does, without risking it being copyrighted. Look into various images from locations that serve unprotected images & cite those in your notes when you respond to the metadata rejection.